# How could I filter output of this in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to filter terminal output of this, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried putting the output into slices, but they output separate slices, and I'm not sure how to join these slices together to make one slice. I haven't found anything helpful when searching for filtering output, so I'm hoping someone can give me a solution. I want to get `//abs.twimg.com`

```
func main() {
    profileURL := "url"
    resp, err := soup.Get(profileURL)
    check("Couldn't send GET request:", err)

    parse := soup.HTMLParse(resp)

    find := parse.Find("head").FindAll("link")
    for _, i := range find {
        links := []string{i.Attrs()["href"]}
        log.Println(links)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//abs.twimg.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//api.twitter.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//pbs.twimg.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//t.co  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//video.twimg.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//abs.twimg.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//api.twitter.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//pbs.twimg.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//t.co  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [//video.twimg.com  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/polyfills.604422d4.js  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/vendors~main.55bd4704.js  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/i18n-rweb/en.15808594.js  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/i18n-horizon/en.d212af84.js  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/main.cc767dc4.js  ]
2020/06/09 08:54:55 [/manifest.json  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps!

```golang
import (
        "log"
        "strings"
)

func main() {
    profileURL := "url"
    resp, err := soup.Get(profileURL)
    check("Couldn't send GET request:", err)

    parse := soup.HTMLParse(resp)

    find := parse.Find("head").FindAll("link")
    filter := make([]string, 0)
    for _, i := range find {
        // map[string]string
        if strings.Contains(i.Attrs()["href"], "//abs.twimg.com") {
                filter = append(filter, i.Attrs()["href"])
        }
    }
    log.Println(filter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
find := parse.Find("head").FindAll("link")
links := make([]string, 0, 1)
for _, i := range find {
    links = append(links, i.Attrs()["href"])
}
log.Println(links)
```

If you know the length of the slice, replace 0,1 with the appropriate values during initialization

Comment: Thanks, this is working :D, I'll try both of these comments out

Comment: But it doesn't filter with `"//abs.twimg.com"`. And both answers are the same by the way except the `strings.Contain` part. I'm not sure what's your requirement?

Comment: yeah, I realised that they are both the same size but yours shows all of the code so it just seemed longer when really it isn't. My apologies for that. I like both of these answers :)

Comment: Did not add the if part as it was obvious, intention was to show how all output results can be collated into one slice